# how to get the name when uploading pfx certificate to Azure Application Gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have asked a customer to export the .pfx file for use in the Application Gateway however when they export it it only provides a password but in Azure it asks for a name and password when uploading the .pfx file as in the attached screenshot? How do you get the name?

[image]

Comment: Hello @itye1970 suggesting you check this link for guide on configuring Azure AG https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-ssl-portal#create-an-application-gateway

Answer (score 3):

This is just the name that you can use to identify the certificate for future reference. Give it any meaningful name that you like

Comment: No worries, feel free to accept the answer if it helped :)